# ReactJS : my object.keys(xxx).map doesn't loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stateless

I tried a lot of things but I'm a beginner in ReactJs and I think It's a simple problem but I can't manage to fix it . I'm using a stateless component because I need to use the function useParams().
I need to loop on my messages so I used   `Object.keys(messages).map( (key) => (...`
But it seems that it doesn't take the proper key because this is what I see on my chrome info on the component :

App -> message key = 'messages'

props message: undefined

pseudo: undefines

My code :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Formulaire from './components/Formulaire';
import Message from './components/Message';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'


function  App () {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState({})

  function addMessage (message) {
    messages[`message-${Date.now()}`] = message // permet d'avoir un TimeStamp unique pour chaque message
    setMessages( messages )
  }
  const {pseudo} = useParams()

  const mess = Object.keys(messages).map( (key) => (
    <Message
    key={key}
    message={messages[key].message} 
    pseudo={messages[key].pseudo} />
  ))
  
  
  return (
    
    <div className="box" > 
      <div>
        <div className='messages'>
          {mess}
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <Formulaire length= {150} pseudo= {pseudo} addMessage = {addMessage} />
    </div>
      
    
  );
}


export default App;
```

**Mes versions**

```
"name": "chat-app",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
   "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
   "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
   "firebase": "^9.6.11",
   "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
   "react": "^18.0.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
   "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
   "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
   "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

Here is a link to a sandbox for my probleme (that is no messages are appaearing)
https://codesandbox.io/s/chat-app-7e2dmw?file=/src/App.js

EDIT : the problem seems to be that the addMessage and the const mess are read on at the refresh of the page and not all the time. Do you know where to put them ?

Comment: can you add a reproducible sandbox for let us debug?

Comment: Thanks I put my code on a sandbox

Comment: Finallys after long research the problem was that the my react app does refresh after an update on the state (an object of objects) in my function compoment. So I don't have the answer but I know where to look. Thanks every one

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is causing you an issue is the way you set your messages.

First, from what I learnt you shouldn't manipulate states values directly unless you are sure of what you are doing. In this case, it seems just fine.

Secondly, you are setting an Object containing your messages object by typing `setMessages({ messages })` and this is why your key becomes messages.

You end up with an object like:

```json
{
    messages: {
        message-timestamp : {},
        message-timestamp2 : {},
        ...
    }
}
```

What you must be trying to do is `setMessages(messages)` to get:

```json
{
    message-timestamp : {},
    message-timestamp2 : {},
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks it solve one problem but I still can't see my messages. But the message are now with the correct key

Comment: The messages appear now (10min after I send them) so there is a problem else where

Answer (score 0):

The problem here for showing the message is that you are assigning wrong variable to the state:

```
function addMessage(message) {
    messages[`message-${Date.now()}`] = message;
    console.log("message", message); // permet d'avoir un TimeStamp unique pour chaque message
    setMessages(message);
  }
```

message is the variable containing datas you need

Comment: if I setMessage on message and not messages it return only the last message send or I want to have the object of all the messages sent